# cabal: how to stop the build on test failure?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, testing, build, cabal

i created tests in HUnit (Tests.hs). i connected them to main: `main = runTestTT tests`. when i do `runhaskell Tests` i see

```
### Failure in: 0                          
T(1)
expected: 145
 but got: 45
Cases: 10  Tried: 10  Errors: 0  Failures: 1
Counts {cases = 10, tried = 10, errors = 0, failures = 1}
```

which is expected. in cabal file i did

```
test-suite xxx
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is: Tests.hs
  build-depends: base ==4.5.*, HUnit ==1.2.5.2, containers == 0.5.5.1
```

and when i do `cabal test` same test logs are written to a file - so i'm sure tests are executed and failing (as expected) but in console i see:

```
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

and the exit code is 0.

so my question is: why cabal claims tests passed and how to make it report errors correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to figure this out myself, this is what I finally got to work....

```
module Main where

import Data.Monoid
import Test.Framework
import Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit
import Test.HUnit

firstTest::Assertion --This one passes                                                                                                                                                                      
firstTest = do
  assertEqual "reward state root doesn't match" (1::Int) 1

secondTest::IO () --This one fails  (note, Assertion is just "IO()", so you can use either)                                                                                                                 
secondTest = do
  assertEqual "empty db didn't match" (1::Int) 2

main::IO ()
main =
  defaultMainWithOpts
  [
   testCase "ShortcutNodeData Insert" firstTest,
   testCase "FullNodeData Insert" secondTest
  ] mempty
```

In my .cabal file

```
Test-Suite test-program
  type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:            Main.hs
  hs-source-dirs:     test
  build-depends:      base
                , test-framework
                , test-framework-hunit
                , HUnit
                , containers
```

then run with `cabal test`

It is tricky, because cabal looks at the exitcode (see the type above), but the HUnit outputs its own messages....  So if you don't return the correct value, you can see output like "test failed" followed by "test passed".  Obviously, the solution is to use the builtin `defaultMainWithOpts`, which does everything correctly.

Comment: it works. thanks! but when all tests pass the output is `1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.`. is there any way to report correct number of passed tests?

Comment: I believe the output is correct.... 1 test *suite* has passed, the number of tests in the suite isn't stated though (you can add other suites in cabal, so the message isn't a trivial one in general, just in the case where there is only one suite).  With exitcode-stdio-1.0, cabal doesn't know the number of tests in the suite, for more detailed data, you can use "detailed-1.0" or "detailed-0.9"....  It is clearly superior, however, you also need to return the appropriate info from main, and from my own playing around, this isn't as well supported as "exitcode-stdio-1.0".

Comment: Thanks for this. I followed your example to get HUnit tests working with `cabal test` without modifying any existing HUnit code. See my [gist](https://gist.github.com/Risto-Stevcev/a9798abc898fba99235b).