# Haskell QuickCheck Test not running properly when run with Cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal, quickcheck

Something did not make sense with a Cabal package I was developing, and I have boiled the issue down to the following example:

I have the following simple test module:

```
module Main where
import Test.QuickCheck (quickCheck)
main = quickCheck False
```

And the following Cabal file in the same directory:

```
name:                project
version:             0.1.0.0
cabal-version:       >= 1.10
build-type:          Simple

executable project
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base, QuickCheck
  default-language:    Haskell2010

test-suite project-test
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base, QuickCheck
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

The only other files in the directory are dist (created by Cabal upon build) and the cabal sandbox files. Both the executable and the test-suite refer to Main.hs, and therefore I would expect to get the same test results when running "cabal run" as when running "cabal test". Apparently, however, that is not the case.

"cabal run" gives:

```
Preprocessing executable 'project' for project-0.1.0.0...
Running project...
*** Failed! Falsifiable (after 1 test):
```

which makes sense because the property test 'quickCheck False' should fail. As expected this is the same result I get when running main in ghci.

"cabal test", however, gives:

```
Test suite project-test: RUNNING...
Test suite project-test: PASS
Test suite logged to: dist/test/project-0.1.0.0-project-test.log
1 of 1 test suites (1 of 1 test cases) passed.
```

Why the heck does "cabal test" pass the test case, whereas "cabal run" fails it as expected?

Comment: I think the first problem will be that the way you write it the "exitcode" will still be ok - tbh: right know why you do not see the output of `quickCheck` (it will probably be suppressed by `cabal test` as it returns **ok**). I usually use [hspec](https://hspec.github.io/quickcheck.html) and it works out fine - maybe you'll give it a try

Comment: well a simple web-search later I found a possible solution for you: [cabal-test-quickcheck](https://github.com/zmthy/cabal-test-quickcheck)

Comment: also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984072/cabal-how-to-stop-the-build-on-test-failure

Answer (score 8):

`quickCheck` doesn't exit the program, therefore, it doesn't set the exit code. After all, you could have several `quickCheck` tests, which should be  independent of each other:

```
main = do
    quickCheck prop1 -- should this exit if the test fails?
    quickCheck prop2 -- should this exit if the test fails?
    quickCheck prop3 -- should this exit if the test fails?
```

However, you can easily fix this if you a) exit as soon as one of your tests doesn't pass or b) remember whether a single test hasn't passed and then exit with the correct code.

## Using only QuickCheck, but no other library

### Exit with failure as soon as a test fails

For this, you simply use `quickCheckResult`, which you can check with `isSuccess` from `Test.QuickCheck.Test`. If you want to use your current  `quickCheck` definition, you can use qualified includes to exchange the default implementation with your special one:

```
import           Control.Monad          (when)    
import           System.Exit            (exitFailure)
import           Test.QuickCheck hiding (quickCheck, quickCheckWith)
import qualified Test.QuickCheck.Test as Q

quickCheckWith :: Testable prop => Args -> prop -> IO ()
quickCheckWith args p = do
      success <- fmap Q.isSuccess $ quickCheckWithResult args p 
      when (not success) $ exitFailure -- exit if the result is a failure

quickCheck :: Testable prop => prop -> IO ()
quickCheck p = quickCheckWith stdArgs p
```

You should probably use another name though, especially if other people work on the same project. `checkOrExit` would be plausible.

### Return failure code but run all tests

This is essentially the same, but runs all test. You must use `quickCheckResult` or `quickCheckWithResult` again:

```
import           Control.Monad          (when)    
import           System.Exit            (exitFailure)
import           Test.QuickCheck        (quickCheckResult)
import           Test.QuickCheck.Test   (isSuccess)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let tests = [ quickCheckResult prop1
              , quickCheckResult prop2
              , quickCheckResult prop3
              , quickCheckResult prop4
              ]
  success <- fmap (all isSuccess) . sequence $ tests
  when (not success) $ exitFailure
```

## Using additional test libraries

While `quickCheck` is great for property checking, it doesn't provide a complete testing framework. That's where other full-fledged frameworks such as [`tasty`](http://documentup.com/feuerbach/tasty) or [`hspec`](http://hspec.github.io/) come in handy. They can take a `Testable a` and inspect QuickCheck's result accordingly. An example using `hspec`:

```
module Main where
import Test.Hspec
import Test.QuickCheck (property)

main = hspec $ do
  describe "<method you would like to test>" $ 
    it "<property/assumption you would like to test>" $ 
       property $ False -- quickCheck
```

This gives the (more verbose) output

```
<method you would like to test>
  - <property/assumption you would like to test> FAILED [1]

1) <method you would like to test> <property/assumption you would like to test>
Falsifiable (after 1 test):
   [remark: the used values would be here, but `False` is a boolean]

Randomized with seed 2077617428

Finished in 0.0019 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Also, it exits with an error code, so your `cabal test` will recognize this failed test correctly. Those test frameworks also have additional features, which go beyond of the scope of this answer.

## TL;DR

QuickCheck doesn't exit your program, but Cabal *only inspects the exit code* to determine whether the tests have passed. Since any regularly ending Haskell program returns zero (aka no error), you either need to use `exitFailure` (or something similar), or a framework that uses `exitFailure` behind the scenes.

Note that this only holds for tests with `type: exitcode-stdio-1.0`.